# Getting grid view in google maps

Tags: android, view, grid, maps

Here I write some application, which shows my location.

In the emulator I get this:

[image: emulator]

But in device I see this:

[image: device]

I connect through wifi, hence there's no problem with internet, it should have opened the map.

What is the reason? How can I solve this?

Thanks.

## Addition

I just regenerated my API key with keytool. Got the same key I had before.

Still the same view in the phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its Google map API key issue you have to re-generate the API key using the keystore which you are using to export your apk.

[Here is how to generate your Maps API Key for final release.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/mapkey)

Comment: Googled a lot, till got the key. Here's how the command should look like in the command prompt (just to help others not to google)
C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin> keytool -v -list -keystore C:\Users\Andranik\.android\MyKeystore

Answer (score 1):

Try opening the default google map application on the device and see if you can load up the map. If you can't then there is some problem with the connectivity. If it is opening the default application then the issue could be of the [API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/mapkey?hl=sv-SE) key for google maps

Comment: Edited my post. Please pay attention.

Comment: @andranikAzizbekyan, how are you deploying the app on device ? are you creating a new apk and then installing it on the device, or are you trying to debug on the device

Comment: Never mind, @Habib.OSU. It was my fault. I was getting the MD5 Fingerprint of the SDK Debug Certificate, instead of Signing Certificate. Now solved. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Add to manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: If I hadn't, then it wouldn't open in emulator too.