# maps not visible in my emulator

Tags: android, google-maps, android-emulator

I am working on location based service project. I want to use maps in my emulator.In my emulator I can't see maps application. How can I see maps in my emulator.

Comment: Why? What have you tried or your effort so far? Any exception, if yes then please post logcat output here.

Comment: Did you generate the map API key ?

Comment: i didn't get any exception. Maps application is not visible in my emulator.

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520791/getting-grid-view-in-google-maps/10520893#10520893

Comment: post some code or give more information.

Comment: @praveenvoggu.. Please post some code what you have tried so far..else everyone will give you different answers and nobody can solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Are you using [Proper API key for map?](https://developers.google.com/android/maps-api-signup) If no, just take from that link. You can't use others map api key and also. So, just try the new API key.
- Check whether you're using proper SDK for Google maps -

  [image]

Answer (score 0):

the AVD prepared might not be of googleapis so might be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have created AVD with

> Google APIs(Google Inc.)

[image]